# React render list only when data source changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Basically I have a modal with a state in the parent component and I have a component that renders a list. When I open the modal, I dont want the list to re render every time because there can be hundreds of items in the list its too expensive. I only want the list to render when the dataSource prop changes.

I also want to try to avoid using useMemo if possible. Im thinking maybe move the modal to a different container, im not sure.
If someone can please help it would be much appreciated. Here is the link to sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/rerender-reactmemo-rz6ss?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

You can use React.memo, for more information about it please check [reactmemo](https://fr.reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo)

```
const List = React.memo(({ dataSource, loading }) => {
  console.log("render list");
  return (
    <div>
      {dataSource.map((i) => {
        return <div>{i.name}</div>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
});
```

[sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/rerender-reactmemo-forked-294j6?file=/src/List.js:28-230)

Comment: When adding the elements to the list it doesnt seem to re render

Comment: Obviousely it won't render, because you declared the list as constant so the reference stay the same, I suggest yout to use useState so it can change it for you, I did an Update please check https://codesandbox.io/s/rerender-reactmemo-forked-294j6?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you want to avoid React.memo, I think the best approach would be to move the `<Modal />` component to another "module"

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Another list={list} />
      <List dataSource={list} />
    </>
  );
}
```

And inside `<Another />` component you would have you `<Modal />`:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Modal } from "antd";

const Another = ({ list }) => {
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <Modal
        visible={showModal}
        onCancel={() => setShowModal(false)}
        onOk={() => {
          list.push({ name: "drink" });
          setShowModal(false);
        }}
      />
      <button onClick={() => setShowModal(true)}>Show Modal</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Another
```

Now the list don't rerender when you open the Modal

Comment: I think that would work the only thing is that my modal function gets called from 2 separate places would I need to have 2 functions separately?

Comment: If your application needs to call the Modal from different places, you can use React Portal and the Context API to create a robust implementation

This is a great follow up: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/build-a-modal-using-react-context-portals-and-hooks-bd0c4e54537e

In my opinion is a great way to handle modals in React

Comment: Wouldnt using the context api still re render the list when the modal opens?

Comment: Not necessarily, you can create the Modal in another module just like I did in the example. The main benefit of a "React Portal + ContextAPI" is the possibility to dispatch an event and open the Modal from anywhere. So if you keep you Modal and List separated, it won't re-render the list